# How to Fix a Run-Time Error While Using For Each Loop

Tags: excel, vba, foreach, runtime-error

I have a code in which I am looping through a range of cells and comparing it to an input box entry. If the cell does not match the entry the code does nothing, if the code does match the entry it clears the contents of the cell. Most of the code has worked fine. The loop variable is correctly showing the value of each cell that it should loop through when monitoring it in breakout mode, and it is successfully comparing it to the input text.

```
        UPC = InputBox("UPC #?")
        For Each b In SRange
            If CStr(b) = CStr(UPC) Then
                b.ClearContents
            End If
        Next
```

The issue that I am running into is that as soon as it finds a match and moves on to the line where it is supposed to do something ( b.ClearContents) It throws a Run-Time Error 424 Object Required fault.

I have tried using several different operations such as b.Address and b.Value, but they all give the same fault. Strangely enough, if I MsgBox(b) it works just fine and shows me the value of the cell.

Comment: What's def of SRange ? Have you tried do define SRange  as object like: Dim SRange  as Objec or as Array of cell values ?

Comment: I am using it to compare strings inside cells to an input through InputBox, so Dim As Object won't work because it's String type cell content. When I try to Dim As Object it errors out on the For Each line saying that b is Nothing. I also tried to Dim As Variant even though I know that is the default just to be extra careful, but it didn't change the outcome.

Comment: Thats the Error. Please define Dim b AS Object, ARange as Object, Set SRange = ActiveSheet.Range("A1:B5") then do the loop. Thus will work.

Comment: I didn't think about Dim SRange As Object. Once I did that it worked. Thank you very much!

Comment: What on earth are you talking about? You have to assign a range to the variable: `Dim SRange As Range: Set SRange = Range("A1:A10"): Dim cell As Range: For Each cell In SRange.Cells: If CStr(cell.Value) = UPC Then cell.ClearContents: Next cell`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This code tested working:

```
Sub so75513894ObjectError()
  Dim SRange As Object
  Dim UPC As String
  'Dim aRange
  
  Dim b
       
  Set SRange = ActiveSheet.Range("A1:B5")
  'aRange = ActiveSheet.Range("A1:B5").Value
  
   UPC = InputBox("UPC #?")
   For Each b In SRange
     If CStr(b) = CStr(UPC) Then
        b.ClearContents
     End If
   Next

End Sub

Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
   so75513894ObjectError
End Sub
```

Comment: Yes Sir, I had tried to define the variable, but I had the SRange As Range. Once I defined it As Object it worked. Thank you very much for your help!

Comment: This is a great pleasure.